# Как посмотреть почту комитера на гитхаб

Tags: github

Есть аккаунт на гитхаб. Там есть репозиторий с комитами. Нельзя отправить комит, не указав имя и емал. Вопрос, вот на гитхабе, когда просматриваешь комиты, имя, которое указал автор, видно, а вот почты я не нахожу. Как мне узнать почту, которую автор указал при комите? Причем мне важно, что именно при комите, а не просто почту, которую указывают для связи в информации.

Comment: Ни в интерфейсе github.com, ни в интерфейсе bitbucket.org, нигде ничего такого и в самом деле нет. Если смысл вопроса только лишь в том, чтобы просто узнать почту контрибьютора, то помогут команды `git log`, `git show` уже локально в папке с репозиторием. Плагины современных IDE для работы с git у себя тоже рисуют почту контрибьюторов.